# DRF serialize ArrayField as string

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a Model with an ArrayField `tags` and I need it to serialize back and forth as a string of values separated by comma.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Snippet(models.Model):
    tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255), default=list)
```

I want this field to be handled as a string of tags like `tag1,tag2,tag3`, I can handle this in the model `save()` method but DRF is complaining with `{tags: ["Expected a list of items but got type "str"."]}`.

**serializers.py**

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Snippet
        fields = ('tags')
```

What can I do in DRF to manage this field as a string ? I am using React in the front-end and I could handle it there but I prefer handling this in the backend rather than the client-side.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a custom field that handles the format that you want
The rest framework mapping field of postgres ArrayField is a ListField, so you can subclass that.

```
from rest_framework.fields import ListField

class StringArrayField(ListField):
    """
    String representation of an array field.
    """
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        obj = super().to_representation(self, obj)
        # convert list to string
       return ",".join([str(element) for element in obj])

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.split(",")  # convert string to list
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

Your serializer will become:

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = StringArrayField()

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('tags')
```

More info about writing rest framekwork custom fields here:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#examples

Comment: This works fine, but the drf web UI still shows the message - "Lists are not currently supported in HTML input.". Is there a way to make this field editable, where we enter comma separated values.

Comment: You should be able to post the json, in drf web UI besides HTML Form there is a 'Raw data' on the left of it, there you can post the json data and enter comma separated values.