# Django rest framework serialize ArrayField as string

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a field in my Model class with an 'ArrayField' and I want it to serialize back and forth as a string of values separated by comma.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class Test(models.Model):
    colors = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20), null=True, blank=True
```

I followed this solution - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170009/drf-serialize-arrayfield-as-string#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170009/drf-serialize-arrayfield-as-string#_=_)

```
from rest_framework.fields import ListField

class StringArrayField(ListField):
    """
    String representation of an array field.
    """
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        obj = super().to_representation(self, obj)
        # convert list to string
       return ",".join([str(element) for element in obj])

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.split(",")  # convert string to list
        return super().to_internal_value(self, data)
```

In Serializer:

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    colors = StringArrayField()

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('colors')
```

But getting bellow error -

TypeError: to_representation() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Please help.

Comment: Pl. share the code of the custom Field class you have used.

Comment: @chatuur I have updated it.Please check:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests you are passing an additional parameter to the method. I noticed that the super() call is incorrect. You can replace that with:

```
        obj = super().to_representation(obj)
```

Comment: This throws an error for me:

`TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`

Comment: You're probably on python2.x. Use super(ClassName, self)