# Django Rest Framework: Serializing splits list of strings into list of characters

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am setting up an API with DRF, everything is going smoothly but I am having a bit of a problem when passing a field with a list of strings

**Json object**

```
    {
        "postID": 1,
        "index": 0,
        "text": "For years you had a President who apologized for America – now you have a President who is standing up for America, and standing up for PENNSYLVANIA. Tomorrow, you have the power, with your vote, to save AMERICA! GET OUT AND VOTE!! #MAGA ",
        "date": "2020-11-02",
        "likesCount": 145000,
        "commentsCount": 4500,
        "sharesCount": 3500,
        "hashtags": [
            "[",
            "'",
            "M",
            "A",
            "G",
            "A",
            "'",
            " ",
            "'"
            "A",
            "G",
            "A",
            "I",
            "N",
            "'",
            "]"
        ]
}
```

Whereas **hashtags** field values should be: "['MAGA' , 'AGAIN']".

How could I override the serializer and prevent that strings are split into characters ?

**models.py**

```
from djongo import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField


# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    index = models.IntegerField()
    postID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField()
    likesCount = models.IntegerField()
    commentsCount = models.IntegerField()
    sharesCount = models.IntegerField()
    hashtags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True), size=50)
    tokens = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True), size=50)
    tagged = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True), size=50)
    keywords = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True), size=50)
    entities = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True), size=50)
    noun_phrases = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True), size=50)
    noun_phrases_keywords = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True), size=50)
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post, Comments


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Serializer inspection**

```
PostSerializer():
    postID = IntegerField(label='PostID', max_value=2147483647, min_value=-2147483648, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Post.objects.all())>])
    index = IntegerField(max_value=2147483647, min_value=-2147483648)
    text = CharField(max_length=500)
    date = DateField()
    likesCount = IntegerField(label='LikesCount', max_value=2147483647, min_value=-2147483648)
    commentsCount = IntegerField(label='CommentsCount', max_value=2147483647, min_value=-2147483648)
    sharesCount = IntegerField(label='SharesCount', max_value=2147483647, min_value=-2147483648)
    hashtags = ListField(allow_empty=False, child=CharField(allow_blank=True, label='Hashtags', max_length=20, required=False), validators=[<django.contrib.postgres.validators.ArrayMaxLengthValidator object>])
    tokens = ListField(allow_empty=False, child=CharField(allow_blank=True, label='Tokens', max_length=20, required=False), validators=[<django.contrib.postgres.validators.ArrayMaxLengthValidator object>])
    tagged = ListField(allow_empty=False, child=CharField(allow_blank=True, label='Tagged', max_length=20, required=False), validators=[<django.contrib.postgres.validators.ArrayMaxLengthValidator object>])
    keywords = ListField(allow_empty=False, child=CharField(allow_blank=True, label='Keywords', max_length=20, required=False), validators=[<django.contrib.postgres.validators.ArrayMaxLengthValidator object>])
    entities = ListField(allow_empty=False, child=CharField(allow_blank=True, label='Entities', max_length=20, required=False), validators=[<django.contrib.postgres.validators.ArrayMaxLengthValidator object>])
    noun_phrases = ListField(allow_empty=False, child=CharField(allow_blank=True, label='Noun phrases', max_length=20, required=False), validators=[<django.contrib.postgres.validators.ArrayMaxLengthValidator object>])
    noun_phrases_keywords = ListField(allow_empty=False, child=CharField(allow_blank=True, label='Noun phrases keywords', max_length=20, required=False), validators=[<django.contrib.postgres.validators.ArrayMaxLengthValidator object>])
```

Answer (score 0):

I got to a solution using [DRF serialize ArrayField as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170009/drf-serialize-arrayfield-as-string/47197709) as a reference :).

**serializer.py**

```
class StringArrayField(ListField):
    
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        
        # convert list to string
        return "".join([str(element) for element in obj])

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.split(",")  # convert string to list
        return super().to_internal_value(self, data)
```