# Serializing Array Field to String

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I have an array field in my model i need to serialize and return the first 10 tags from the query getting error while serialising the data.

referred - [DRF serialize ArrayField as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170009/drf-serialize-arrayfield-as-string#)

**serializers.py**

```
class StringArrayField(ListField):
    """
    String representation of an array field.
    """
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        obj = super().to_representation(self, obj)
        # convert list to string
        return ",".join([str(element) for element in obj])

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.split(",")  # convert string to list
        return super().to_internal_value(self, data)

class TagsSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = StringArrayField()

    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ('id', 'tags')
```

**models.py**

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
       tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True),default=list, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class TagsSearchAPIView(APIView):
"""
Used on dropdown menus to dynamically fetch Tags data
"""

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Mymodel.objects.all()
        tags = queryset.order_by('tags')[:10]
        serialized_tags = TagsSearchSerializer(tags, many=True, context={'request': 
        request})
        results = serialized_tags.data

        return Response({'results': results})
```

error

```
 to_representation() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: try removing the super line `obj = super().to_representation(self, obj)` - that's where the two arguments are coming from.. normally it should be something like `super(self).to_representation(obj)` but I don't think a super is necessary in that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to pass `self` keyword into `super().to_representation(obj)`. Try this one

```py
def to_representation(self, obj):
    obj = super().to_representation(obj)
    # convert list to string
    return ",".join([str(element) for element in obj])
```