# DRF modelserialize string to list

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a model TempDiamondModel which has a manytomany field called Gemstone. After an ajax POST call the value for Gemstones is a string (like "32,30", in the request.data).

From examples and sources like:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47197709/10709524
2. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#examples

I derived my serializer as follows:

```
    class StringArrayField(ListField):
        """
        String representation of an array field.
        """
        def to_representation(self, obj):
            obj = super().to_representation(self, obj)
            # convert list to string
            return ",".join([str(element) for element in obj])

        def to_internal_value(self,instance, data):
            data = data.split(",")  # convert string to list
            return super().to_internal_value(self,data)

    class TDiaSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        Gemstones = StringArrayField()
        class Meta:
            model = TempDiamondModel
            fields = ['Name','Type','GWT','Colour','Clarity','Carat','Cut','Shape','Gemstones','GGWT','Location','PAmount','SAmount']
```

but i keep getting an error like

```
   TypeError: ListField.to_internal_value() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

what is the thrid argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `to_internal_value` takes two parametsrs: the `self` (implicitly) and the `data`, so:

```
class StringArrayField(ListField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):  # 🖘 only data
        data = data.split(',')
        return super().to_internal_value(data)  # 🖘 only pass data
```

That being said, I would *strongly* advise not to do this. Imagine that you have as data:

```
"foo, bar","qux"
```

Then it seems evident that `"foo, bar"` is the first item, and `"qux"` the second, but here you will construct three items `"foo`, `bar"`, and `"qux"`, which will also have an invalid format.

Only if the type of items you want to serialize can not contain a comma, that is a sensical option.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the ans, i have dicided to take ur advice and approace this in the modelviewset create fn